# whats wrong with my c++ boost regex function?

Tags: c++, regex

## include

```
#include <algorithm>
#include<boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include<boost/regex.hpp>
  using namespace std;
  using namespace boost;

  string _getBasehtttp(string url)
  {

        regex exrp( "^(?:http://)?([^\\/]+)(.*)$" );

        match_results<string::const_iterator> what;

        if( regex_search( url, what, exrp ) )

        {

            string base( what[1].first, what[1].second );

            return base;
        }
        return "";
 }
int main( ) {

   cout << _getBasehtttp("httpasd://www.google.co.in");
}
```

if i input `http://www.google.co.in` i am getting returned as `www.google.com` but if i input `httpasd://www.google.co.in` i am getting `httpasd` ..there should not be any match na y i am getting the match ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^(?:http://)?([^\\/]+)(.*)$`

the ? at the end of `(?:http://)?`  means that bit is optional
this `([^\\/]+)` captures and matches anything that is not a \ or /
this `(.*)` captures everything else up to the end of the line

Perhaps your after something more like
`^(?:https?://)([^\\/]+)(.*)$`

might like to consider full URL syntax along the lines of

```
 file://                                        /C:/temp/app/example.html
 file://     C                             :    /temp/app/example.html
 file://     C                             :    \temp\app\example.html
 http://user@www.hotmail.passport.login.net:8080/test/url.htm?view=smart
[method][               server                   ][   path   ][optional]
        [user][         domain             ][port]
```

Then your heading for a regex more like

```
([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\-\\.]*://)?(([^@/\\\\]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9_'!~\\-,;&=\\.\\$\\*\\(\\)\\+]+)(:\\d*)?)?([/\\\\][^?]*)?(\\?.*)?
```

Answer (score 2):

The `http://` doesn't match, but then it's optional, so that's no problem; the "one or more characters that aren't slashes" matches `httpasd:`, and of course the `.*` then matches everything that follows, from the slashes (included) onwards.  This would work the same way with any common regex implementation, nothing c++ specific about it!

Comment: @raj, that entirely depends on _what_ you're trying to match, and what you're trying **not** to match.  I'm glad @Greg was able to divine that (I infer from your acceptance), because my thought-reading abilities are limited;-).